# Render Error Can't find variable React in RN cli

Tags: react-native

[image]
[image]

I already imported **react** but can't find it.
I use RN cli.
(It worked well in EXPO cli, but I copy&paste the code to convert not to eject)
PLASE HELP ME~ Thank you!!

```
    This error is located at:
        in RootNavigator (at App.js:12)
        in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
        in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
        in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
        in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:11)
        in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:87)
        in SafeAreaProvider (at App.js:10)
        in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
        in RCTView (at View.js:32)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
        in RCTView (at View.js:32)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
        in RNSTAMPY(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
     ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React
```

Comment: Please add code as text inside code blocks - images are difficult to read and aren't indexed for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import React at the top of each file it is used. You imported it in your App.js, but probably not in navigations.js.